# Python a badly formatted JSON with "extra" double quotes

Tags: python, json, formatted

I need some help!!

I need to handle in Python a badly formatted JSON with "extra" double quotes. Unfortunately it is not possible to adjust at the origin. Any idea how I can fix this???

**Bad JSON**

```
json_input='{"value_ok" : "ok", "empth" : """", "value_2" : ""text"", "value_3" : ""2022-01-01""}'
```

**Attempt 1**

```
d = json.loads(json_input)
...
JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 33 (char 32)
```

**Attempt 2**

```
d = benedict.from_yaml(json_input)
...
expected ',' or '}', but got '<scalar>'
  in "<unicode string>", line 1, column 33:
    {"value_ok" : "ok", "empth" : """", "value_2" : ""text"", "value ...
```

**Expected result ...**

```
json_adjusted='{"value_ok" : "ok", "empth" : "", "value_2" : "text", "value_3" : "2022-01-01"}'
d = json.loads(json_adjusted)
print(d)
```

```
{'value_ok': 'ok', 'empth': '', 'value_2': 'text', 'value_3': '2022-01-01'}
```

Comment: Did you forgot to show sample "badly formatted" json? What does "extra double quotes" mean?

Comment: I'm curious about this `origin` and why `"it is not possible to adjust"`.

Comment: As you say, the sender is sending you invalid JSON.  That's what needs to be fixed.  You can edit the string yourself before parsing, but it won't be easy.  That's why people make standards.  You can replace `""""` with `"\""`, but getting the other instances is tricky.  A double quote that is not preceeded by `:` or followed by `,` needs to be replaced with `\"`.

Comment: I'm trying to regularize at the origin, unfortunately whoever takes care of the application is not willing to make the correction :(
I agree with standards, as they exist they must be respected.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to substitute `: ""` and `"",`, but I would be careful as this could break the document in other places.

```py
import re
json_input = re.sub(r'""([,}])', r'"\1', re.sub(r': ""', r': "', json_input))
```

Comment: I tried and it didn't work...

Result: 
{"value_ok" : "ok", "empth" : "", "value_2" : "text", "value_3" : "2022-01-01""}

Comment: @ANDREDEANDRADEFERREIRA I see, because it failed to replace the final double-double quote before the closing brace. I have updated my answer to handle this. Still note that this is nothing more than a hack. If you expect JSON, the producer must produce valid JSON.